# Clojure: Find missing records in a collection based on another collection

Tags: clojure

I have 2 vectors: employ and emp-income. I want to loop thru emp-income based on employ to find what all the missing records. In this case, it's missing id = 2. And i want to create the missing record in emp-income and set the income as the previous record's income value. What is the best way to do it in clojure?

```
(def employ
  [{:id 1 :name "Aaron"}
   {:id 2 :name "Ben"}
   {:id 3 :name "Carry"}])
```

from:

```
(def emp-income
  [{:emp-id 1 :income 1000}
   {:emp-id 3 :income 2000}])
```

to:

```
 (def emp-income
      [{:emp-id 1 :income 1000}
       {:emp-id 2 :income 1000}
       {:emp-id 3 :income 2000}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
(let [emp-id->income (into {} (map (fn [rec] [(:emp-id rec) rec]) emp-income))]
    (reduce (fn [acc {:keys [id]}]
                   (let [{:keys [income]} (or (get emp-id->income id) (peek acc))]
                     (conj acc {:emp-id id :income income})))
                 []
                 employ))
```

Note this will create a record of `{:emp-id id :income nil}` if the first record is not found in `emp-income`. It will also use the last `:emp-id` encountered if duplicate `:emp-id` values are found within `emp-income`.